# AssertionError on PUT unit TestCase

Tags: python, django, validation, testing

I'm creating a unit test for a PUT method which purpose is creating new database entry. The problem seems to be I can't retrieve the saved fields string in the right format. The result strings are surrounded with square brackets.
Faulty part of `tests.py`:

```
        def test_create_task(self):
        self.client.login(username='user1', password='password1')
        data: dict[str, str] = {
            'name': 'Nowe zadanie',
            'description': 'Nowy opis',
            'status': 'Nowe',
            'username': 'user1',
        }
        response = self.client.post('/api/tasks/', data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(Task.objects.count(), 4)
        self.assertEqual(Task.objects.last().name, 'Nowe zadanie')
        self.assertEqual(Task.objects.last().description, 'Nowy opis')
        self.assertEqual(Task.objects.last().status, 'Nowe')
        self.assertEqual(Task.objects.last().user, self.user1)
```

`create` method from `views.py`:

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid username.')

        request_data = request.data.copy()
        request_data.pop('username', None)

        task = Task.objects.create(user=user, **request_data)
        serializer = TaskSerializer(task)
        response_data = serializer.data
        response_data['username'] = user.username

        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

`Task` model class from `models.py`(im also using `django-simple-history` library):

```
class Task(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('Nowe', 'Nowe'),
        ('W toku', 'W toku'),
        ('Rozwiązane', 'Rozwiązane'),
    ]
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Nowe')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

console output:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_create_task (tasks_app.tests.TaskTestCase.test_create_task)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hunes\Desktop\Studia\tasks_project\tasks_app\tests.py", line 48, in test_create_task
    self.assertEqual(Task.objects.last().name, 'Nowe zadanie')
AssertionError: "['Nowe zadanie']" != 'Nowe zadanie'
- ['Nowe zadanie']
? --            --
+ Nowe zadanie
```

I tried converting single-quoted strings in data with double-quoted ones, adding type hint to data, converting dict lateral to constructor and seeking help online. When I'm testing the API from Swagger's level I get the expected result, that being saved objects aren't surrounded by the square brackets

> Sorry if i used some bad nomenclature, I'm starting to learn the language